# Syncing Oneplus 3 contacts to PC?

Tags: sync, oneplus-3

The title says it all:
I want my OnePlus 3 to automatically sync my contacts to my PC (Google)

I've been asking Oneplus, but they either have no idea or aren't willing to share it.

One supporter even said that these phones don't sync contacts!

Anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone should always sync contacts as long as you are using a Google Account. You can always go to Settings->Accounts->Google and check if "Contacts" is enabled to make sure that they are being synced. If you want to view them on a PC go to the [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) website.

Comment: I've been doing that for months.  
I do realise that it's 'supposed' to sync automatically,,,, but it dosn't.  
When I look at settings>accounts>google, everything is ON.  
Almost everything says "synced today at whatever time it is", but it dosn't.  
If I add a contact to the PC, it will sync to the phone,,,, but not the other way round.

Comment: ?????????????I'm still struggling,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea. Do the contacts just not show up like, ever, on a PC when you add it via a phone?

Comment: If I add contact to phone, it dosn't sync with PC.  

If I add contacts to PC, it does sync to phone.

Comment: Still struggling,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
OnePlus don’t read my messages, as they keep repeating “do a reset”, which I’ve now done half a dozen times.  
It never, ever, makes a difference. 
When I tell them that, they say “carry out a reset” ?!

Comment: By PC, where exactly are you checking for contacts?